# ansible uri module with form

Tags: module, scripting, uri, ansible

Is it possible to run this command with uri module in ansible ?

```
- shell: unset http_proxy && curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control:no-cache" -F "access_key={{ api_user }}" -F "secret_key={{ api_pass }}" "http://mydomain.bla/api/v1/login_check"
```

I tried like this:

```
- uri:
    url: http://mydomain.bla/api/v1/login_check
    method: POST
    user: "{{ api_user }}"
    password: "{{ api_pass }}"
  environment:
    http_proxy: ''
```

And like this:

```
- uri:
    url: http://mydomain.bla/api/v1/login_check
    method: POST
    body: "access_key={{ api_user }}&secret_key={{ api_pass }}"
  environment:
    http_proxy: ''
```

And still does not work.
I'm trying to get a token and store it in an ansible variable.

"use_proxy: false" or no does not work - that's why I'm using this ugly environment workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use `return_content: yes`

From module's [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html):

> `return_content` (default: no) – Whether or not to return the body of the request as a "content" key in the dictionary result.

```
- uri:
    url: http://mydomain.bla/api/v1/login_check
    method: POST
    body: "access_key={{ api_user }}&secret_key={{ api_pass }}"
    return_content: yes
  register: token_response
  environment:
    http_proxy: ''

- debug: var=token_response.content
```